# SagePay Token Integration PayPal Token

Tags: paypal, opayo

It's not clear from the SagePay docs if the Token integration works for **PayPal transactions**.

It doesn't appear to.

The token docs state that:

> If you wish to register this transaction as the first in a series of
> regular payments, this field should be set to 1.
>
> If you do not have a
> PayPal account set up for use via Sage Pay, then this field is not
> necessary and should be omitted or set to 0.
>
> 0 = This is a normal
> PayPal transaction, not the first in a series of payments (default)
>
> 1
> = This is the first in a series of PayPal payments. Subsequent payments can be taken using TxType=REPEAT.

**Questions:**

1. To repeat a SagePay PayPal transaction is it necessay to use the REPEAT transaction type outlined in the shared protocol guidelines documentation.
2. As SagePay archive transactions after two years, is there a way that we could increase the life of a subscription beyond two years?
3. Is the token supplied by SagePay in the notification for a PayPal transaction useful?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. You could possibly switch to repeating the repeat (if that makes sense! Not sure if it would work though)
3. Not really. You handle everything through the Sage Pay interface, so you don't need anything from Pay Pal